# How do I push a NuGet package from Appveyor build only if all builds in matrix are successful?

Tags: appveyor

I have a library with source code hosted on GitHub and configured to build on Appveyor CI (e.g. https://github.com/vostok/temp-library/blob/master/appveyor.yml).

I'd like to build and test this library on different platforms:

- .NET Framework on Windows
- .NET Core on Windows
- .NET Core on Ubuntu

Naturally, I would configure a build matrix to build on different platforms. But then, I'd like to build and push a NuGet package *only* if all builds on all platforms were successful.

How do I configure something like this on Appveyor?

Comment: Each job in this matrix produces it's own artifacts. Which artifacts you plan to publish to Nuget?

Comment: I’d like to run tests on Ubuntu and Windows, and build a package on Windows only if tests on all platforms were successful.

Answer (score 0):

To run tests on Ubuntu and Windows, you also need to build before. So what you need to do is to make Windows job to wait for others (I am not sure which Windows job, as you have 2 of them but I believe you know).

So to make one matrix job wait for others, you need to do some scripting. Please use this sample as a reference.

```
write-host "Waiting for other jobs to complete"

$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $env:ApiKey"
  "Content-type" = "application/json"
}

[datetime]$stop = ([datetime]::Now).AddMinutes($env:TimeOutMins)
[bool]$success = $false

while(!$success -and ([datetime]::Now) -lt $stop) {
    $project = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/$env:APPVEYOR_ACCOUNT_NAME/$env:APPVEYOR_PROJECT_SLUG" -Headers $headers -Method GET
    $success = $true  
    $project.build.jobs | foreach-object {if (($_.jobId -ne $env:APPVEYOR_JOB_ID) -and ($_.status -ne "success")) {$success = $false}; $_.jobId; $_.status}
    if (!$success) {Start-sleep 5}
}

if (!$success) {throw "Test jobs were not finished in $env:TimeOutMins minutes"}
```

If you have more than one concurrent job, you can make it wait longer. If you have only one concurrent job, make it wait less (because with one concurrent job when last job started, others already finished one way or another)

To make this script and Nuget deployment run only in specific Windows job, [specialize matrix job configuration](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#specializing-matrix-job-configuration)

`$env:ApiKey` you get at https://ci.appveyor.com/api-token and store as [secure variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables).

Comment: If I recall correctly, Free, Basic and Pro plans all have a limit of 1 concurrent job. I don't need a Premium plan, because I'm okay with all builds in a matrix running consecutively. But this code seems to require a Premium subscription, because a sleeping job is still a job, and it will lock queued jobs indefinitely waiting for them.